# Concatenate range of cells with criteria in a column

Tags: vba, concatenation

I need help with vba concatenate cells.

I have a spread sheet:
column A contain values like Product A for a few rows, Product B for a few rows, and so on.
I want to concatenate, say cells in columns B-J for Product A, write the value to column K or another sheet, then do the same thing with Product B, and so on till the end of the spreadsheet.

I think this would need some vba coding which I am learning but not good yet to do the job. Please help!

Thank you,
cj

Comment: Your question Title mentions `Criteria`. Can you explain what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

> > > I think this would need some vba coding

No you don't need vba for this :)

Put this formula in K1 and drag it down

```
=B1&" "&C1&" "&D1&" "&E1&" "&F1&" "&G1&" "&H1&" "&I1&" "&J1
```

This will concatenate the data with `SPACE` as a delimiter. If you do not want space then amend the above formula to

```
=B1&C1&D1&E1&F1&G1&H1&I1&J1
```

Similarly if you want to concatenate with `COMMA` as a delimiter then use this

```
=B1&", "&C1&", "&D1&", "&E1&", "&F1&", "&G1&", "&H1&", "&I1&", "&J1
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I read it as you want everything in a single column into another cell. This is a routine that will take all the data from the cell you specify, and concatenate everything going down until there is a break in the data

```
Option Explicit

Function ColConc(CellRef As Range, Delimiter As String)

Dim LoopVar As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim Concat As String
Dim Col As Long

Col = CellRef.column
StartRow = CellRef.Row
EndRow = CellRef.End(xlDown).Row

Concat = ""

For LoopVar = StartRow To EndRow
    Concat = Concat & Cells(LoopVar, Col).Value
    If LoopVar <> EndRow Then Concat = Concat & Delimiter
Next LoopVar

ColConc = Concat
End Function
```

call by using the formula `=ColConc(A2," ")` and this will get everything from cell A2, down to the end of that column, with a space as the delimiter.
The delimiter can be any string, so you can place anything between the data. A blank cell ends the data it uses for concatenating into a single string.
It will only work on the current sheet - more coding would be needed to get that part working